# sending konckoutjs ViewModel as data throught ajax

Tags: json, model, knockout.js

for populating search form with data i'm using following ViewModel:

```
 function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.Countries =[{"id": "1","name": "Russia"},{"id": "2","name": "Qatar"}];
    self.selectedCountryId =ko.observable();      
 }
```

I need Countries list for populate dropdwonlist. 
When user fills the form and clicks "send", i need to submit the data, but i do not need to send the Countries list!
(only SelectedCountryId)

```
var vm=new AppViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);

$('button').click(function(){

  console.log(ko.mapping.toJSON(vm));

});
```

Is there the way to get rid of countries list without build new ViewModel for sending?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look into this demo I've created for you [Click here for the DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pkysylevych/dqUAz/)

**Updated Demo [Click here for the updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pkysylevych/dqUAz/2/)**

**HTML Code**

```
<select data-bind="options: countries, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', value: selectedChoice, optionsCaption: 'Choose..'"></select>
<br/>
<label data-bind="text: selectedChoice"></label>
```

**Javascript Code**

```
var CountryModel = function(data){
  var self = this;
  self.id = ko.observable(data.id);
  self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
};
var viewModel = function(data) {
  var self = this;
  self.selectedChoice = ko.observable();
  self.countries = ko.observableArray([
      new CountryModel({id: "1", name: "Russia"}),
      new CountryModel({id: "2", name: "Qatar"})]);
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

**START UPDATE**
**What is updated:**
**HTML Code:**
Added button on event Click it calls `sendMe` function which returns json object of `selectedCountryId`

```
<input type="button" data-bind="click: sendMe, enable: selectedChoice" Value="Click Me"/>
```

**Javascript Code**

```
self.sendMe = function(){

    alert(ko.toJSON({ selectedCountryId: this.selectedChoice()}));
};
```

**END UPDATE**

**START UPDATE1**
This is update for the last comment, regarding avoid addition model, in this case let's skip `CountryModel`
So, the **Javascript Code** will be the following:

```
var viewModel = function(data) {
   var self = this;
   self.selectedChoice = ko.observable();
   self.countries = ko.observableArray([
        {id: "1", name: "Russia"},
        {id: "2", name: "Qatar"}]);
    self.sendMe = function(){
        alert(ko.toJSON({ selectedCountryId: this.selectedChoice()}));
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

**END UPDATE1**

Hope, it will help you.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for answer but i think i did not explain my problem well anougth: 
when sending data to server you need only selected id's of all lists but not te lists themselfs,
thats why it bothering me when i get json after "ko.mapping.toJSON"
which looks like this:
{\"Countries\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"Russia\"},{\"id\":\"2\",\"name\":\"Qatar\"}],\"selectedCountryId\":\"2\"}"
instead of:

Comment: Ok, please take a look on this updated jsFillde [new demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pkysylevych/dqUAz/2/). I think that is what you needed.

Comment: exactly:
{"selectedConutryId":"2"}
only this i wnat to send to server
Thanks

Comment: That means the only way- is to create new Model which not contains lists properties...
(which frustrating if you have many collections)
anyway Thanks

Comment: Actually, you don't need create additional Model, I've updated my answer (START UPDATE1 - END UPDATE1)

Answer (score 1):

Observables are just like normal functions, so you just need to call it from outside.

```
function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.Countries =[{"id": "1","name": "Russia"},{"id": "2","name": "Qatar"}];
    self.selectedCountryId = ko.observable('1');      
}

$(function() {
    var vm = new AppViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);

    $('button').click(function(){
      console.log(vm.selectedCountryId()); // plain
      console.log(ko.toJSON(vm.selectedCountryId())); // json
    });
});
```

​

http://jsfiddle.net/DiegoVieira/6kZMj/4/